# How to get users count per seconds in mongo db aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Would like to get the active login users count per seconds interval in mongo db aggregation.

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "user" : "user1"
    "start" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:03.000Z"),
    "ended" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:05.000Z"),
    "duration": 2
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "user" : "user2"
    "start" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:02.000Z"),
    "ended" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:06.000Z"),
    "duration": 4
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "user" : "user3"
    "start" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:03.000Z"),
    "ended" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:06.000Z"),
    "duration": 3
},
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "user" : "user1"
    "start" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:08.000Z"),
    "ended" : ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:09.000Z"),
    "duration": 1
}
```

ie. shown below are graphical representation to as per records available in the database.

```
 Secs   0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9--10
 user1           |-----|        |--|
 user2        |-----------|
 user3           |--------|

Result  0  0  1  3  3  3  2  0  1  1  0  <= Active users for every seconds
```

(assume $lte and $gte to include boundaries)

Below expected result range between ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:00.000Z") and ISODate("2021-05-31T04:01:10.000Z"),

**Expected result:**

```
{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:0},
   activeSessioncount : 0
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:1},
   activeSessioncount : 0
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:2},
   activeSessioncount : 1
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:3},
   activeSessioncount : 3
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:4},
   activeSessioncount : 3
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:5},
   activeSessioncount : 3
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:6},
   activeSessioncount : 2
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:7},
   activeSessioncount : 0
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:8},
   activeSessioncount : 1
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:9},
   activeSessioncount : 1
},{ 
   _id : {day:31,hour:4,min:1,seconds:10},
   activeSessioncount : 0
}
```

I would like to thank advance and any references related to above scenario would be helpful .

Comment: Another similar scenario is showing chart  for calls per seconds

Comment: any reference would be appreciated

Comment: any suggestions please